# Polynomial differential forms on $BG$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, simplicial-stuff

Let $\Omega^{*}_{\text{poly}}\: : \: sSet\to dg_{\geq 0}Comm_{+}$ be the polynomial De Rahm functor on simplicial sets, where the codomain is the category of commutative differential graded algebras over a field of charachteristic zero. Let $G$ be a group, what is $\Omega^{*}_{\text{poly}}(BG)$? Its cohomology? Do you have some references for that?

Comment: For the case when $G$ is such that it makes sense to speak about its Lie algebra, see [this nlab entry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Weil+algebra#weil_algebra_of_a_lie_algebra)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field of characteristic zero.

For any simplicial set $Y$ denote by $RY$ its topological realization then you have an isomorphism of graded algebras:
$$H^*(\Omega_{poly}^*(Y,\mathbb{F}))\cong H^*_{Sing}(RY,\mathbb{F}).$$
Any book about rational homotopy theory will be a good reference:

- A. K. Bousfield and V. K. A. M. Gugenheim, On $\mathrm{PL}$ de Rham theory and rational homotopy type, Mem. Amer. Math. Soc. 8 (1976), no. 179
- Griffiths, P.; Morgan, J. (1981), Rational homotopy theory and differential forms, Progress in Mathematics, 16, Birkhäuser
- ...

Edit: let me give you a conceptual proof

- 1) you have a first adjunction
  $$\Omega^*_{Poly}:SSets^{op}\leftrightarrows cdga_{\mathbb{F}}:\mathfrak{R}$$
  this is a Quillen adjunction we get on homotopy classes:
  $$[Y,\mathfrak{R}A^*]_{SSets}\cong [A^*,\Omega^*_{Poly}(Y)]_{cdga_{\mathbb{F}}}.$$
- 2) let $\Lambda_{\mathbb{F}}(x_n)$ be the free graded commutative algebra on a generator $x_n$ of degree $n$ we have:
  $$[\Lambda_{\mathbb{F}}(x_n),B^*]_{cdga_{\mathbb{F}}}\cong H^n(B^*)$$
  putting 1)+2) together we have that $H^n(\Omega^*_{poly}(Y))\cong [Y,\mathfrak{R}\Lambda_{\mathbb{F}}(x_n)]_{SSets}$.
- 3) We use the fact that $\mathfrak{R}B^*$ is fibrant (it is always a Kan simplicial set) and the Quillen equivalence between SSets and Top (given by the realization and the singular set of a topologica space) to get that
  $$[Y,\mathfrak{R}B^*]_{Ssets}\cong [RY,R\mathfrak{R}B^*]_{Top}$$
  this gives us: $H^n(\Omega_{Poly}^*(Y))\cong [RY,R\mathfrak{R}\Lambda(x_n)].$
- 4) The last step is the identification of $R\mathfrak{R}\Lambda(x_n)$ together with the Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(\mathbb{Q},n)$.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to me that if the simplicial set is the nerve of some group, then you get the group cohomology with coefficients in the field of charachteristic zero. I'm wrong?

Comment: Exactly, you are right, you get group cohomology.